# Passing Elasticsearch and Kibana config file to docker containers

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, kibana, kibana-4

I have found a docker image [devdb/kibana](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/devdb/kibana/) which runs `Elasticsearch 1.5.2` and `Kibana 4.0.2`. However I would like to pass into this docker container the configuration files for both `Elasticsearch` (i.e elasticsearch.yml) and `Kibana` (i.e config.js)

Can I do that with this image itself? Or for that would I have to build a separate docker container?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can I do that with this image itself?

yes, just use [Docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/docker/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems) to pass in your own config files

Let say you have the following files on your docker host:

- /home/liv2hak/elasticsearch.yml
- /home/liv2hak/kibana.yml

you can then start your container with:

```
docker run -d --name kibana -p 5601:5601 -p 9200:9200 \
    -v /home/liv2hak/elasticsearch.yml:/opt/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml \
    -v /home/liv2hak/kibana.yml:/opt/kibana/config/kibana.yml \
    devdb/kibana
```

I was able to figure this out by looking at your image Dockerfile parents which are: [devdb/kibana](https://github.com/abh1nav/docker-kibana/blob/master/Dockerfile)→[devdb/elasticsearch](https://github.com/abh1nav/docker-elasticsearch/blob/master/Dockerfile)→[abh1nav/java7](https://github.com/abh1nav/docker-java/blob/master/Dockerfile)→[abh1nav/baseimage](https://github.com/abh1nav/docker-baseimage/blob/master/Dockerfile)→[phusion/baseimage](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker/blob/master/image/Dockerfile)
and also taking a peek into a `devdb/kibana` container: `docker run --rm -it devdb/kibana find /opt -type f -name *.yml`.

---

> Or for that would I have to build a separate docker container?

I assume you mean *build a separate docker image?*. That would also work, for instance the following Dockerfile would do that:

```
FROM devdb/kibana
COPY elasticsearch.yml /opt/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
COPY kibana.yml /opt/kibana/config/kibana.yml
```

Now build the image: `docker build -t liv2hak/kibana .`

And run it: `docker run -d --name kibana -p 5601:5601 -p 9200:9200 liv2hak/kibana`

Comment: I found another issue.I tring opening http://docker_ip:5601 - it said webpage not available connection refused after I run sudo docker run -d devdb/kibana. Is there anythong else that I need to do? port mapping perhaps?

Comment: that should then be another question

Comment: Will the single image create restriction on my ability to create elasticsearch cluster later if I wanted to?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what you are asking. Do you mean _single container_? Docker images aren't run, they are containers blueprints from which you can run multiple containers.

Comment: I guess what I am asking is if I were to run multiple containers will it produce two Kibana and two ElasticSearch. I am looking for an elasticsearch cluster talking to the same kibana

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28632977/elasticsearch-in-docker-container-cluster

Comment: I think I may be missing something. My concern is because ES + Kibana are part of the same container. I understand the part about how to cluster elasticsearch instances.