# How to join ElasticSearch cluster with nodes in docker instance

Tags: elasticsearch, docker

I am running a docker image that has ElasticSearch inside, which maps to hosts port 38xxx:9200, what I want to do is also run ElasticSearch on host computer so that the host and the docker one will form a cluster, so I don't have to copy the ES data out from docker instance. Is this possible? And how do I configure the ports to achieve this?

I had a quick look at this one but doesn't seem to answer my question directly...
[Elasticsearch in docker container cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28632977/elasticsearch-in-docker-container-cluster)

Comment: Why not stoping ElasticSearch on the host computer and starting a new one with shared volume to make your cluster easily ?