# How do I modify the cluster name of an elastic search instance?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I've moved from the [official version](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html) to the now deprecated [docker hub version](https://github.com/docker-library/elasticsearch) of elasticsearch [version 5.5.2](https://github.com/docker-library/elasticsearch/blob/094b4b6bff8626a2391404413a2e338c48ef7a26/5/Dockerfile).

In the official version, the recommended way of setting the name of the cluster is to pass it as an environment variable `- cluster.name=docker-cluster`. This method does not work in the docker hub version. It uses  the default name "elasticsearch" despite the environment variable.

Referring an earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28632977/elasticsearch-in-docker-container-cluster), I experimented by overriding the command in the docker-compose file to `command: [ "elasticsearch", "-Des.cluster.name=another-name" ]` but this causes the container to not start at all.

Is there a way to override the cluster name without using a custom configuration file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker logs <container>` on the restarting container displayed the correct syntax to use. The syntax that worked was `command: ["elasticsearch", "-Ecluster.name=es-cluster"]`